# http request a firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, http-post

Estoy intentando hacer que al momento de hacer un petición http al mi firebase function, este me mande "Hello Fernando", pero aún no lo he podido conseguir, he estado buscando en foros y encontré qué primero tengo que convertir mi `request` a un `String`.

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const info = request.params;
    const data = JSON.stringify(info);

    response.send("Hello " + data.name);
});
```

El resultado que me manda es el siguiente:

```
Hello undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien más tiene problemas lo unico que hice fue cambiar el request.params por request.query

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var name = request.query.name || "unknown";

    response.send("Hello " + name);
});
```